# MIPS Conditional Statement BNE is always branching

Tags: string, loops, assembly, mips

```
loop:
    lb  $t0 0($a0)
    beqz    $t0 done        
    bne $t0 $a1 continue

    sb  $a2 0($a0)

    continue:
    addi    $a0 $a0 1
    j   loop
```

This loop is just going over a string, except I can't figure out why the statement `bne $t0 $a1 continue` still branches even when I am checking in `xspim` and they are equal.

Basically the program should not branch when `$t0 == $a1`. `$a1` is the `' '` character, and then it should move onto the statement `sb $a2 0($a0)`. So I am stepping through in `xpsim` and when `$t0 = 20` (in hexidecimal, so ASCII code is `' '`), so this should be equal to `$a0` which is also `' '`.

Therefore, it should not branch into the continue statement and execute the statement below it. I guess my reasoning is not correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. I wrote a SPIM-program to test this:

```
.data       
str:    .asciiz "test test test"

.text
main:
    la      $a0, str
    addi    $a1, $zero, 32
    addi    $a2, $zero, 64

loop:   
    lb      $t0, 0($a0)
    beq     $t0, $zero, done
    bne     $t0, $a1, continue
    sb      $a2, 0($a0)

continue:
    addi    $a0, $a0, 1
    b       loop

done:   
    addi    $v0, 4
    la      $a0, str
    syscall

    addi    $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall
```

And it returns "`test@test@test`", as expected. Be aware that in 'real' MIPS, some things might be unexpected for you:
1. Branches have a branch-delay slot, the instruction after the branch is executed regardless of whether the branch is taken.
2. Branches cannot be in the branch-delay slot of another branch.
Make sure you haven't set SPIM to simulate a raw MIPS-machine, or your code won't work.

Comment: I don't get it, my program is so similar to yours, but yet it wont place stuff inbetween the spaces! Strange. See when I was stepping through in xspim it would jump over "sb   $a2, 0($a0)" so I was thinking that this is why the spaces aren't being filled. I will look around for other errors, but it is very strange how similar yours is, and yet it works! Thankyou though!